# Replace first @ with {{ 2nd @ with }}

Tags: java, regex, replace

I've got a file that has values that start with @ and end with @

I need the first @ to be replaced with {{ and the second @ with }} for the entire document so far I've got no luck.

Seen a lot of solutions regarding replacement but not for this. Hope someone can help me out. 
Thx!

Comment: We can't see your XML file, but that doesn't matter because you should not be using regex to parse XML.

Comment: in the end the file extension doesn't matter for my problem thx for reviewing the post though

Comment: usually when xml and regex are together, it might not be the best way to go.

Comment: You can extract every thing between the two dollars then put the result between `{{` and `}}`  `xml = xml.replaceFirst("@(.*?)@", "{{$1}}");`

Answer (score 1):

You could match and `@`, then using a negated character class match not an `@` and capturing that in a group (captured group 1) and finally match an `@` again. That as the replacement use `{{group1}}`

**Match**

[`@([^@]+)@`](https://regex101.com/r/Evib2R/1)

**Replace**

`{{$1}}`

**Example code**

```
String regex = "@([^@]+)@";
String string = "@testvalue1@ text @testvalue2@ text";
String subst = "{{$1}}";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex, subst));
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QPYKY21725)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this regex:

```
    @.*?@
```

Then replace the first match with other matchs.

Comment: use this `@(.*?)@` instead of `@.*?@` not the catch group check my comment and the [ideo demo](https://regex101.com/r/YDyH5y/1)